# Needs alternative solution to Thread.sleep();

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Web-driver,i that architecture is designed by the Selenium IDE component and for other events core java methods are implemented.
The main problem that I ma facing currently is,I have to design my Script according to the Speed of the Internet,And most of time script crashes because of time out error.

To overcome this problem I am implementing the "Thread.Sleep();" java method.
But with this solution,system automation got slow,And System has to wait till the Thread gets its timer completed.

So,I need an optimized solution for this problem like A method which will hold the further action till the complete page got loaded.

Comment: Mohit, you can find hell number of threads for Synchronization in WebDriver. You can google it with implicitWait and WebDriverWait. These two are better than Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Hi Uday,Actually i don't want to hold the script execution for predefined amount of time.Rather that doing this I am working on a solution that will provide me functionality like:- Automation script should pause till the entire page and all events on that page got loaded.Please provide a solution for this problem if possible.

Answer (score 4):

you can also try out this code that waits for the browser to provide whether page loaded or not.

```
objExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) objDriver;
if (!objExecutor.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString()
    .equalsIgnoreCase("complete")){
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

You can simply put it in your base page so you wont need to write it down in every pageobjects. I have never tried it out with any AJAX enabled sites, but this might help you and your scenario dependency will also get away.

I prefer to use the FluentWait API of Selenium. By using it you can additionally set a maximum waiting time (.withTimeout) and can also ignore certain exception. This is especially important when you use FluentWait to search for elements on a page:

```
public void waitUntilDocumentIsReady() {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(this.webDriver())
            .withTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(UnhandledAlertException.class);

    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver f) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) f).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

From Selenium documentation ([selenium](http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/)), you can use  implicitly wait:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

This will tell the driver to wait at maximum 10 seconds before failing, but it will automatically loop to see if the result is ready before. If it is ready, then the method continues without waiting 10 seconds. Please not that the value will be set for the whole selenium script.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having one big Thread.Sleep and hoping the next piece will be ready when you're finished, you can break it up into a number of retries.

So (pseudo code) instead of:

```
doSomething();
Thread.sleep(5000);
doNextThing(); //Let's hope we're ready at this point...
```

You could do:

```
doSomething();
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(isNextBitReady()) 
    {
        break;  //Yay! Give up sleeping and carry on
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);  //Sleep a little bit and try again
    }
}
doNextThing();
```

This means your wait time will hopefully be usually shorter, but you still have a safety net if a particular run is slow.  You can balance the number of retries and the sleep time to get finer-grained checks.

Comment: I was thinking more or less the same thing, the only _issue_ is whether or not some sort of `isNextBitReady` method is available?