# Is there any way in Selenium 2 where the script should know that web-page is Loading and hence it should wait?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have a Situation where i am using *Sikuli* to detect image. In my case the Image is displayed but the Web-Page still shows Loading.So when Sikuli tries to click on the image it does not selects the image  so my script gets pass even though i have not selected image.Any suggestion. How i can handle this situation?

Comment: Are you using both Selenium and Sikuli? Your title makes it sound like Selenium needs to do the waiting, but your actual question makes it sounds like Sikuli needs to do that waiting--can you clarify what exactly is happening?

Comment: hope this might help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101399/needs-alternative-solution-to-thread-sleep/27101691#27101691

Comment: @autoKarma : Which ever is more effective. I want  sikuli to  click on image only  after loading of webpage completed.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you can use Selenium WebDriver. If this is the case Selenium should wait untill the page loads. That being said, you can use the following code to see if the page loads.

```
int count = 0 ; 
String state = "";
do {
    state = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readystate");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} while ((!state.equals("complete"))&&count<15);
```